# Random results spaced in specific time (according to column data)

Tags: mysql, sql, random, distance

I've those 2 tables in MySQL
- "tag_name" which contains an unique `tag_name_id` of each individual created tag, and the respective `tag`
- "tags" which contains also an unique `tags_id`, a `timecode` (time instant) and `group_id` (same tags can have different group_id)

Now, what I'm trying to do is getting a random `timecode` somewhere in the first 10 seconds (`timecode <= 10`). And after that, and according to that timecode extracted, try to select all the results that are distanced by 3 or more seconds. (all the results less than 3 seconds must be discarded).

Example:
If I have these results in my database:

```
2,3,4,4,6,13,14,17,18,18,21,25,28,28,etc (timecodes)
```

I want to grab one of the first 10 randomly (lets say I pick the 4) and then I want to start sorting them randomly according to that time instant. ("randomly" because I want to change the order when same timecode instants appears ie: "4,4" because they are associated to different tags, so I want them to "switch" between them, so I can pick up a different one every time)
So the result query came in something like this: 4,13,17,21,25,28,etc

I already have this query that returns me the random number, and this morning I have been trying to make a Select inside the Select because I think the answer is there, but I can't retrieve the results I want, and I also can't find a way to retrieve result distanced by 3...

```
SELECT tag_name.tag, ROUND(avg(timecode)) as timecode, group_id 
FROM tags
INNER JOIN tag_name
ON tag_name.tag_name_id = tags.tag_name_id
WHERE tags.filename = 'filename.mp4' AND timecode <= 10
GROUP BY  group_id, tag_name.tag
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4438/5) is the SQLFiddle

Comment: There's exactly one 'timecode' per second?

Comment: Yes! All 'timecodes' are inserted in seconds...

Comment: That's not what i said! Now I'm very confused. Do you want your first result to be a random result from amongst the first ten entries (i.e. 2 through 18) OR from within the first 10 seconds (i.e. 2 through 6?)

Comment: Ah ok! Now I understand, but it's not too relevant. It could be the first 10 entries!

Answer (score 0):

So we have a table of timecodes which, for the sake of argument, might look like this...

```
CREATE TABLE timecodes(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,timecode INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO timecodes (timecode) VALUES (2),(3),(4),(4),(6),(13),(14),(17),(18),(18),(21),(25),(28),(28);

 SELECT * FROM timecodes;
 +----+----------+
 | id | timecode |
 +----+----------+
 |  1 |        2 |
 |  2 |        3 |
 |  3 |        4 |
 |  4 |        4 |
 |  5 |        6 |
 |  6 |       13 |
 |  7 |       14 |
 |  8 |       17 |
 |  9 |       18 |
 | 10 |       18 |
 | 11 |       21 |
 | 12 |       25 |
 | 13 |       28 |
 | 14 |       28 |
 +----+----------+
```

Now, this question is in two parts. The first part concerns obtaining a random result from within the first *n* results. One way of doing that (although probably not the fastest way) is like this...

```
 SELECT @seed := x.timecode 
   FROM timecodes x 
   JOIN timecodes y 
     ON y.id <= x.id 
  GROUP 
     BY x.id 
 HAVING COUNT(*) <= 5 
  ORDER 
     BY RAND() 
  LIMIT 1;

+---------------------+
| @seed := x.timecode |
+---------------------+
|                   4 |
+---------------------+
```

This query generates a seed (in this case '4'), which can be ploughed back into subsequent queries, e.g.;

```
SELECT @seed := MIN(y.timecode)
  FROM timecodes x
  JOIN timecodes y 
    ON y.timecode >= x.timecode + 3
 WHERE x.timecode = @seed;

1st iteration
+--------------------------+
| @seed := MIN(y.timecode) |
+--------------------------+
|                       13 |
+--------------------------+

2nd iteration    
+--------------------------+
| @seed := MIN(y.timecode) |
+--------------------------+
|                       17 |
+--------------------------+

3rd iteration    
+--------------------------+
| @seed := MIN(y.timecode) |
+--------------------------+
|                       21 |
+--------------------------+

4th iteration    
+--------------------------+
| @seed := MIN(y.timecode) |
+--------------------------+
|                       25 |
+--------------------------+

5th iteration    
+--------------------------+
| @seed := MIN(y.timecode) |
+--------------------------+
|                       28 |
+--------------------------+

6th iteration    
+--------------------------+
| @seed := MIN(y.timecode) |
+--------------------------+
|                     NULL |
+--------------------------+
```

This can be wrapped up in a sproc, or some application level code that says 'do the first thing then, while @seed is NOT NULL, do the second thing' - but that's a step beyond my pay grade.

Comment: [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4438/5) is an example of my DB. The SQL Query that I've presented returned me a random number of the first 10 results. And I think the one you've posted returned the same but with a different approach.  
For the second part, what I need to do is select all the results separated by 3 or more seconds, starting from the returned `timecode` from the previous query...

Comment: "I think the one you've posted returned the same" No. Yours returns results from within the first 10 seconds. Not the same thing. And edit your original question to include the link to the fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! And about the second part, do you any clue how to do it?

Comment: Could you please give me a hand on this? I really don't know how to grab the spaced results in time taking into account the returned result from the query... Thank you.

Comment: See Edit above. The problem is it's procedural (iterative). So I think you need to write a sproc, or handle the logic at the application level. i don't think you can do this just with 'in-line' variables.

Comment: This is level is too high for me! I don't think I've too much knowledge to keep on this query... But I will analyse your edit, and try to explore some approach. Thank you.